# Commit android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, git, git-commit

Создаю абсолютно чистый проект, хочу сделать коммит в `BitBucket` и выскакивает ошибка для многих файлов:

> The following problems have occurred when adding the files: fatal: LF
>   would be replaced by CRLF in gradlew  during executing git "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors --
>   gradlew

Подскажите еще какие основные файлы нужно коммитить чтобы потом импортировать рабочий проект из репозитория

Comment: Пожалуйста, один пост - один вопрос. Возможно [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf) уже есть ответ. Выполнить команду `git config --global core.safecrlf false`

Comment: где это написать в android studio?

Comment: Полагаю в командной строке.

Comment: я не использую командную строку, делаю коммит и push через андроид студио в bitbacket

Comment: git config --global
 Можно прописывать откуда угодно. (ИЗ обычной командной строки, из ИДЕ, из гит баша и т.д (

Answer (score 2):

В *Android Studio* есть "вшитый" (встроенный терминал [*bash*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash), смотреть внизу картинки):

[image: Окно Android Studio]

Там введите и выполните команду `git config --global core.safecrlf false`

После этого выполните все свои *ранее* выполненные действия, все должно быть хорошо ;)